# Do you know how to setup Wand on Mac?

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I just want to be able to import Wand and use it on Python on my Mac but it doesn't seem possible anymore.

I have updated and cleanup homebrew, then run `brew install imagemagick@6`

Then I `export MAGICK_HOME=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.12-40` because that's where my imagemagick is located.

I also have most recent version of wand installed, then when I try to do `from wand.image import Image` in python3 I get this error message :

```
OSError: cannot find library; tried paths: [ ... ]
```

Where ... contains the right paths which I can see do contain the files for imagemagick.

So if the path is right, why is Wand still not working?

Answer (score 5):

I found I needed this prior to any Python usage of `wand` on **macOS** V12.2.1 with **ImageMagick** installed via **homebrew**:

```
export WAND_MAGICK_LIBRARY_SUFFIX="-7.Q16HDRI;-6.Q16HDRI"
export MAGICK_HOME=/opt/homebrew
```

---

Presumably that enabled it to find these:

```
/opt/homebrew/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.dylib
/opt/homebrew/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.dylib
/opt/homebrew/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.10.dylib
/opt/homebrew/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.10.dylib
/opt/homebrew/lib/libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.5.dylib
/opt/homebrew/lib/libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.dylib
```

Comment: Amazing answer - not sure I could have stitched that together from the wand docs.  Thank you.